# Getting ALL shops, with `attached` if a given item is attached to it

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables. `items`, `shops` and a pivot, `shop_item`.

I want to retrieve *all* shops, but with an extra field, `attached` if a given item is attached to the shop.

The below works, but it doesn't specify the item to set the `Attached` parameter on.

I image a `WHERE shop_item.item_id = 1` somewhere, but I haven't managed to get it working.

How can I implement the parameter?

```
SELECT shops.*, shop_item.id AS attached FROM shops
LEFT OUTER JOIN shop_item
ON shops.id = shop_item.shop_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to put this condition in the `on` clause, not a `where` clause:

```
SELECT shops.*, shop_item.id AS attached
FROM shops LEFT OUTER JOIN
     shop_item
     ON shops.id = shop_item.shop_id and shopt_item.item_id = 1;
```

If you put it in the `where` clause, it will "undo" the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, turning it into an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want attached items, then use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT shops.*, shop_item.id AS attached
FROM shops
    INNER JOIN shop_item ON shops.id = shop_item.shop_id
```

If you want a boolean value for `attached` then you'll need to evaluate the value, but leave it as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT shops.*,
    CASE WHEN shop_item.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END CASE AS attached
FROM shops
    LEFT OUTER JOIN shop_item ON shops.id = shop_item.shop_id
```